# Where is application-scope location of resources in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I am wrapping some 3rd party application into Eclipse plugin.

This application uses some data files in "current" directory, i.e. directory where application ran from.

Initially I put all of theses files at first level in Eclipse plugin project and can access these files via

```
bundle.getEntry("./conf/conf.xml")
```

unfortunately, this code creates strange URLs like

```
bundleentry://88.fwk1692538903/./conf/conf.xml
```

Why is it so? Is it possible to put all application-scoped files into some global location and refer it from a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator` to convert the `bundleentry` URL to a normal `file` URL:

```
URL bundleURL = bundle.getEntry("...");

URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(bundleURL);
```

Note: If the plugin is in a jar rather than expanded during install the URL returned may reference a temporary location in the metadata where the plugin has been expanded.